# 405 Method not allowed -while calling wcf service using jquery ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, jsonp

When I try to call wcf service from `$.ajax` method I am getting following Exceptions.

```
1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) 

2. Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

AJAX Coding

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        async: false,
        url: "http://localhost:65201/Empservice.svc/getEmployee",
        crossdomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            try {
                response = data;
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Excpetion " + errorThrown + XMLHttpRequest);
        }
    });
```

Comment: url what you specified is incorrect use url:"your url"

Comment: [Have a read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: you make a request to cross domain but you defined your dataType as JSON. Change to JSONP and if you trying to access your localhost file mention your ip address inside your url ex:url"yourIpAddress/Empservice.svc/getEmployee"

Comment: when use url as string pattern in ajax call after that too we are facing the same response

Comment: we used jsonp instead of json then following method not fire it.
success: function (data) {
            try {
                response = data;
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        },

Comment: because we are getting undefined data in response after execute it

Comment: **It is not possible to make a JSONP POST request**. but i need to use post method to achieve execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid 405 Method not allowed error try to add following coding in wcf serivce Global.asax file.it working for me

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                           "Accept, Content-Type,customHeader");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                          "POST,GET,OPTIONS");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
                          "172800");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
                          "true");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
                          "customHeader");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-type",
                         "application/json");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                           "Accept, Content-Type,customHeader");


            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
                          "customHeader");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-type",
                         "application/json");

        }


    }
```